# css: first-of-type not addressed correctly after class changed (by owl carousel)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a carousel, generated by OWL. All the visible containers have the class "active", the invisible 'off-stage' containers don't. So I basically want to address the first visible container using something like this:

`.owl-item.active:first-of-type .item {
    border:4px #369 solid;
}`

So after moving the first image off-stage the related part of carousel code looks ikes this:

```html
<div class="owl-stage">
<div class="owl-item"><div class="item"><img src="/content/uploads/wdc-3.jpg"></div></div>
<div class="owl-item active"><div class="item"><img src="/content/uploads/wdc-2.jpg"></div></div>
<div class="owl-item active"><div class="item"><img src="/content/uploads/wdc-1.jpg"></div></div>
</div>
```

The problem is: the CSS marker "first-of-type" will *not* recognize the "new" first element. In this case: after the first carousel-change NO element will have the designated border ('4px #369 solid'). What am i missing?

Thank you! Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.owl-item.active .item { border:4px #369 solid; }
.owl-item.active ~ .owl-item.active .item { border:none; }
```

Problem is that css doesn't provide a `:first-of-class` selector that only chooses the first occurrence of a class.

**Demo**

```css
.owl-item.active .item { border:4px #369 solid; }
.owl-item.active ~ .owl-item.active .item { border:none; }
```

```html
<div class="owl-stage">
<div class="owl-item"><div class="item"><img src="/content/uploads/wdc-3.jpg"></div></div>
<div class="owl-item active"><div class="item"><img src="/content/uploads/wdc-2.jpg"></div></div>
<div class="owl-item active"><div class="item"><img src="/content/uploads/wdc-1.jpg"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What a brilliant worakaround! And i even semm to understand, how/why it works! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jquery then `eq` will help you,Just add this line in js section

```js
$('.active').eq(0).css('border','1px solid')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-stage">
<div class="owl-item"><div class="item"><img src="/content/uploads/wdc-3.jpg"></div></div>

<div class="owl-item"><div class="item"><img src="/content/uploads/wdc-3.jpg"></div></div>

<div class="owl-item active"><div class="item"><img src="/content/uploads/wdc-2.jpg"></div></div>

<div class="owl-item"><div class="item"><img src="/content/uploads/wdc-3.jpg"></div></div>

<div class="owl-item active"><div class="item"><img src="/content/uploads/wdc-1.jpg"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you!! it's working when i set eq to 1 ("eq(1)") in right-scrolling direction – but when scrolling back all the elements keep their property they received through eq(1), although i hard-added different properties for eq(2) and eq(3) etc. through jQuery…?! arrrghh